# Url.Page automatically ToLowers any values passed in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a .netcore3 app with IdentityServer, and in the [example](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity-configuration/sample/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/ForgotPassword.cshtml.cs) ForgotPassword page (which I'm using), they generate a token for the user and email it like this:

```
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ResetPassword",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                    Input.Email,
                    "Reset Password",
                    $"Please reset your password by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

Then in the ResetPassword class, it resets the password using the token passed in (plus the user and the new password) `var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, Input.Code, Input.Password);`

However, the Url.Page call at the top takes the code and lowercases the whole thing, which I believe is causing the ResetPasswordAsync to throw InvalidToken.

Any idea how I can get Url.Page to generate an absolute url without lowercasing the code?

Answer (score 0):

In my Startup.cs, I had

```
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
        });
```

Once I removed that, it fixed the reset password.  Now I just have to make sure I didn't break anything else in the process